# Order products by association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Class Product

```
has_many :sales

end

Class Sale

belongs_to :product

end
```

How do i get the most sold products.. (Product find all.. order by .. ventas..) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When retrieving the Products, you could do:

```
 @products = Product.find(:all, :include => :sales, :order => "sales.value DESC")
```

'sales.value' can be replaced with whatever value you are trying to order by...

---

**EDIT:** Disregard the rest of my answer. it won't return the Product objects in descending order by sale value, it'll return the Sales objects associated with the Product in descending order by sale value. :P

Also, you can specify the ordering in your model like:

```
    Class Product
        has_many :sales, :order => 'sale_value DESC'
    end
```

where the 'sale_value' is whatever you're trying to order by... and doing it this way, to retrieve the Products, you can just do:

```
 @products = Product.all
```

Comment: @kchau In your second example `@product.sales` would be affected by the `:order` clause, but not `Product.all` Tou would still need to specify it this way: `Product.all(:include => :sales)`

Answer (score 15):

You might want to hit two birds with one stone (the other bird being performance) by using a  counter cache column in the product model. For instance, say you make a sale for product X. When that sale is committed to the database, it will run a callback to increase the number of sales for that product in the product's row in the database. When you destroy, it conversely decreases the number of products.

You'd need to set up a cache column in the products table. In a new migration, do this:

```
add_column :products, :sales_count, :integer, default => 0

Product.reset_column_information

Product.all.each do |product|
  Product.update_counters(product.id, :sales_count => product.sales.length
end
```

You'd also need to make some changes to your Product and Sale models, like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then, instead of having to load all of the sales associations (which, in a large app, would be treacherous), you'd just load the product, and you'd have the number of associated sales in the row itself, for a fraction of the cost of performance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here's the link to the according doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache

Comment: Some production systems might find the above migration slow when there's over 10,000 records etc.

For a SQL version, you can do something like 
`UPDATE products SET sales_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE sales.product_id = products.id)` (postgresql)

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to order the products by the number of sales associated with them, it can actually be kind of a difficult problem, depending on your database.  Googling dug up an answer from [transientink.com](http://transientink.com/articles/how-to-order-by-association-count-in-rails), but this solution does not work for me personally.  I suspect it's because of differences in how PostgreSQL handles GROUP BY clauses compared to MySQL.

Another option is to enable [counter_cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) on the product association in Sales (see the link for the details) and sort by the counter cache field.

Another option is to use Ruby for the sorting:

```
@top_products = Product.find(:all, :include => :sales).sort_by { |p| p.sales.size }
```

There are 2 major issues with this, the first is that you are leveraging your web server to do the sorting, which will slow down requests (perhaps noticeably, depending on the number of products.)  Second, you can't make use of the :limit option in the finder, so if you only want the top 10 most sold products, you have to fetch them all from the DB, sort them in your application, and then limit them afterwards.