# sorting in has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, has-many-through

I have a category model, An Image model and a User model

```
  Category:
      has_many :images
      has_many :users, :through=>'images'


  Image: 
    belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :user

  User:
      has_many :images


   Category.first.users //returning users but its not ordering ie :order=>' images uploaded by users in that category DESC'.
   Category.all.collect(&:users)  //returning users but its not ordering ie :order=>' images uploaded by users in that category DESC'..
```

- I need list of users for that category having top 25 users having maximum number of images in that category.
- I need top 25 users in two or more categories something like top 25 users in category 1 and 2.

Comment: I think there is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760404/order-products-by-association-count

Comment: @BenMiller no that is for has_many relationship where sorting is based upon a column value, but i need sorting based on number of images counts in that category, by that user

Comment: have you tried adding the :order field to the relationships?

Comment: what version rails?  I'll try to mock something up

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
Category.first.images.group(:user_id).count(:user_id, :order=>"count_user_id desc").map {|k,v| k}.first(25)
```

That will give you an ordered array of the top 25 user ids posting images to the category.

To do this all in one query, i believe you would need to do a more complicated select (find by sql)