# Rails default scope ordering based on association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Library`, a `Library` has many `Book`s.

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_collectings
  has_many :books, through: :book_collectings
```

How do I use `default_scope` so that `Library.all` is ordered based on the number of books the `Library` has? (Or is there a different approach?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with the advice of this accepted answer:

[Overriding a Rails default_scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834159/overriding-a-rails-default-scope)

Avoid default scope if at all possible. Even if you used just a scope, to be performant, I think you'd have to write some SQL which might be kind of a pain and may not be portable. I'd recommend considering a counter cache column. Here's the appropriate Rails guide reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache

You'll need to create a migration. See this answer for some sample code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794235/149156

After creating the column, you can then create a scope or class method to order by the book count column.

Comment: Agreed in that default_scope's almost always end up being evil.